# in Perl sendmail, why is my Image attachment becoming corrupt, sometimes?

Tags: perl, email, sendmail, attachment, corruption

I intend to rewrite this in Net::SMTP but right now i need a backup subroutine that doesn't "use" much, so;

The code works and sends emails, when received in most email service (Godaddy,ProtonMail) i get the full image, but in another (34SP) email service i only get the top half of the image.

```
my $msg = "From: John <$sender>
To: bob <$recipient>
Subject: $subject
MIME-Version: 1.0     
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"BOUNDARY\"

--BOUNDARY        
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"MSGBOUNDARY\"

--MSGBOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body>Hello, World<br><img src=\"cid:hello\"></body></html>
--MSGBOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Disposition: inline

Hello, World,[you're missing an image here]
--MSGBOUNDARY--
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"hello.jpg\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Id: <hello>

$jpgg 
--BOUNDARY--";

open MAIL, "| $sendmail -t" 
        or die "Couldn't pipe to $sendmail";
print MAIL $msg;
close MAIL;
```

[image]

I've tested the 34SP email service by sending this first attachment from another location and it receives it fine, so it must be a problem with the code.  If anyone can see something I've done wrong, I'd appreciate it.

EDIT(1); as per Polar Bears suggestion I've edited the code for easier reading, I've tested this version and am still getting the same issue.

Comment: It is not the problem, but it's better to do `open my $mail, '|-', 'sendmail', '-t' or die "sendmail failed: $!";` (then using `$mail` for the following code)

Comment: How are you generating the contents of the `$jpgg` variable?

Comment: It's possible that some services are expecting a `Content-Length` header indicating the size of the (encoded) image

Comment: Grinnz; I'm using base64-image.de to encode, shouldn't be the problem as two out of three email services are reading it.. I know i should use die more often. Content-Length is a good lead thanks, not sure the data Content-Length takes, i tried 7928 (number of characters) without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to change the code to following form

```
my $msg = "
From: John <$sender>
To: bob <$recipient>
Subject: $subject
MIME-Version: 1.0     
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"BOUNDARY\"

--BOUNDARY        
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"MSGBOUNDARY\"

--MSGBOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body>Hello, World<br><img src=\"cid:hello\"></body></html>
--MSGBOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Disposition: inline

Hello, World,[you're missing an image here]
--MSGBOUNDARY--
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"hello.jpg\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Id: <hello>

$jpgg
--BOUNDARY--
";

open MAIL, "| $sendmail -t" 
        or die "Couldn't pipe to $sendmail";

print MAIL $msg;

close MAIL;
```

Comment: @ikegami -- the author of the post have followed my suggestion and modified his original code/post. Before in his code there was **print MAIL ...** for each line -- excessive use of unnecessary typing [less readable code].

Comment: Well for me it is not a problem to add  blank line, but the original post did not include them (I have preserved as it was in original code posted -- added empty line only where **\n\n** was included into printed line). If you have an access to original post then it would be beneficial to check it.

Comment: Well, I can not prove the changes I did but in notepad++ I made following replacements: **\n\n** => blank line, removed **print MAIL "**, removed **\n";** -- the result is what was included into my _answer_ where I indicated that it suggestion only. Of course I could missed something -- but honestly  I put significant attention when I made changes, then just copied result.

Comment: ah, a transparent edit. My apologies. And woops, didn't notice you had done the edit